# React functional HOC component with Hooks, copying static methods

Tags: higher-order-functions, react-hooks, wix-react-native-navigation

I have a functional HOC component that uses hooks.

I am using Wix Native Navigation and most of my screen are using static methods.

But static methods are not copied over when using HOC:

> When you apply a HOC to a component, though, the original component is
>   wrapped with a container component. That means the new component does
>   not have any of the static methods of the original component.

I am trying to use `hoistNonReactStatic` but without success:

Here is my HOC:

```
const WithOfflineAlertContainer = WrappedComponent => (props) => {
  const isConnected = useNetInfo();
  return hoistNonReactStatics(
    <Fragment>
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      {!isConnected && <OfflineAlert />}
    </Fragment>, WrappedComponent,
  );
};
```

this is how is use the `hoc` with `wix-react-native-navigation` :

```
  Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux(screens.gallery, () => WithOfflineAlert(Gallery), Provider, store);
```

But it doesnt seem to work, as I don't see the styles applied from `static options()` from [wix native navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/styling?id=styling-options)

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to make it work using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227055/2829540) from another post.

Here is the working version

```
const WithOfflineAlert = (Component) => {
  const WrappedComponent = (props) => {
    const isConnected = useNetInfo();
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Component {...props} />
        {!isConnected && <OfflineAlert />}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
  hoistNonReactStatics(WrappedComponent, Component);
  return WrappedComponent;
}
```