# NextJS useRouter error when used inside function body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I hope this is a simple question. I can't figure out *why* it's doing this. Anyways, using NextJS i'm trying to access the params in the router using the useRouter hook and combining it with the querystring plugin to split asPath, since NextJS doesn't allow you to access the query part of the router if using stateless. This is my code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import queryString from "query-string";

const withPageRouter = (router) => {
    router.query = { ...queryString.parse(router.asPath.split(/\?/)[1]) };
    return router;
  };

function getRouterParams(){
  const router = useRouter();
  router = withPageRouter(router);
  return router;
}

export async function getTown() {
const town = await getRouterParams();
return town;
}
```

NOw when I attempt to run it, I get this error:

```
Server Error

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

lib/api.js (34:26) @ getRouterParams

  32 | 
  33 | function getRouterParams(){
> 34 |   const router = useRouter();
     |                          ^
  35 |   router = withPageRouter(router);
  36 |   return router;
  37 | }
```

But to me it looks like it should be fine; it is in a function body? I feel like i'm missing something obvious. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Man of Action is correct. You need to import router directly as `import router from "next/router"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't be call useRouter() in normal function.

You can call only useRouter() inside of Top of the React function component or custom hooks

Learn more about Rules of Hooks here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `useRouter` you might want to use `withRouter` (can be used for class components). Also see following related SO question:

[How to use "useRouter()" from next.js in a class component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027469/how-to-use-userouter-from-next-js-in-a-class-component)

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import React from "react";

export default withRouter(class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{ this.props.router.query.id }</div>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The hook should be in react Functional component not inside a normal function or on the top. The component should also be a client component.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!