# Beginner question struggling with React Component implementation getting strange "this" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Beginner question struggling with React Component implementation.
I have tried everything in the cookbook on this error but no luck.

> Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'aaaa'

What is wrong with his code:

```
import React from 'react';

class TestStuff extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.aaaa = this.aaaa.bind(this);
    }

    aaaa() {
        console.log('dddddd');
    }

    render() {
        return <div>test</div>;
    }
}

export default TestStuff;
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected 'this' to be used by class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249478/expected-this-to-be-used-by-class-method)

Comment: I don't think you're defining the function properly. Try ```const aaaa = () => { console.log('dddddd'); }```

Comment: @StephenTaylor this is a `React.Component` I'm suppose to `bind` the function in constructor I think what you propose is for functional components

Comment: @EmileBergeron I do `bind` in the constructor so my Q is not a duplicate like you proposed

Comment: @Kid look at the other answers in the linked thread, it's simply an eslint rule which you could ignore or disable, or change your code to conform without any real impact either way.

Comment: @EmileBergeron it's not an [Eslint rule error](https://snipboard.io/BkYiZw.jpg).  I just made this questions simpler removing code that was not responsible.

Comment: @Kid it is. It's even visible in the screenshot you shared: `eslint(class-methods-use-this)`. It's possibly just integrated in both VS Code and Create-React-App, making it seems like it's a critical error in the build step.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is just saying, I see that you have this method in this class but it's not using any properties in the class. So either make it a `static` method or access a class property inside the method.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this

Comment: I do use [use](https://snipboard.io/tTFu6C.jpg) the method I just made this questions simpler removing  code that was not responsible

Comment: @kid you use the method _but the method does not use the class_, that's what the warning is saying.

Comment: it's not a warning if you use the method or not. The warning is saying, the method `aaaa` needs to access class properties (if you use properties like `this.someVariable`, if you don't use that then just put a `static` keyword in front of the method.