# Invalid Hook Call in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Getting invalid hook call if I use setState for class component or useState for functional component.

```js
const [reviewData,setReviewData]=React.useState(undefined);

     fetch('/reviewAll/')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                  if(data !== null || data !== undefined){
                    console.log(data)
                    this.setState({reviewData:data}) or setReviewData([]); <---------------------------------
                }
          })
```

if I comment out `setState(or useState)`, it's working fine. Tried with axios as well.

Comment: Can we see the contents of your App.js file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371440/10321531

Comment: and you're for sure using a pure component?

Comment: @codemonkey, yeah you are right, no issue with code, its with environment only. Used same code in another project, it worked. Maybe some issue in that react app I created.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Snippet is working fine without error.

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [reviewData, setReviewData] = React.useState(undefined);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setReviewData(data))
  }, [])

  if (!reviewData) {
    return <div> no data </div>
  }
  return <div> {reviewData.name} </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the code she posted. I think it has to do with her environment.