# How would you use conditional hooks inside a React.Component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Per documentation, Hooks cannot be used inside class components. But there are ways with higher order components: [How can I use React hooks in React classic `class` component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371356/how-can-i-use-react-hooks-in-react-classic-class-component). However this answer provided does not address the case of hooks that get called on function invocation. Take this simple Toast hook from: https://jossmac.github.io/react-toast-notifications/. I'd like to call the hook inside of a class of form:

````
```
    class MyClass extends React.Component {
        
        onTapButton = () => {
               
            if(conditionTrue){
                addToast('hello world', {
                     appearance: 'error',
                     autoDismiss: true,
                })
            } 
        }
        
        render(){ ... }

   }
```
````

There'd be no way of calling `addToast` without using `const { addToast } = useToasts()` in the class method, which would throw error.

Comment: @NicholasTower would you provide an example? should I write a function for `addToast` and pass it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withToastManager` HOC to archive that work

Here is an example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withToastManager } from 'react-toast-notifications';

class ConnectivityListener extends Component {
  state = { isOnline: window ? window.navigator.onLine : false };

  // NOTE: add/remove event listeners omitted for brevity

  onlineCallback = () => {
    this.props.toastManager.remove(this.offlineToastId);
    this.offlineToastId = null;
  };
  offlineCallback = id => {
    this.offlineToastId = id;
  }

  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { isOnline } = this.state;

    if (prevState.isOnline !== isOnline) {
      return { isOnline };
    }

    return null;
  }
  componentDidUpdate(props, state, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot) return;

    const { toastManager } = props;
    const { isOnline } = snapshot;

    const content = (
      <div>
        <strong>{isOnline ? 'Online' : "Offline"}</strong>
        <div>
          {isOnline
            ? 'Editing is available again'
            : 'Changes you make may not be saved'}
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    const callback = isOnline
      ? this.onlineCallback
      : this.offlineCallback;

    toastManager.add(content, {
      appearance: 'info',
      autoDismiss: isOnline,
    }, callback);
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default withToastManager(ConnectivityListener);
```

For more information you can also find [here](https://jossmac.github.io/react-toast-notifications/)

Comment: when i do `{ toastManager } = this.props` after wrapping it in `withToastManager` HOC, I'm getting `toastManager` is undefined.

Comment: Did you add `ToastProvider` outside your component?