# Passing Route Parameters in React Using React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React-Router-Dom V6 Preview I am having issues passing the parameters to a component. Here is index.js file with all the routes.

```
 <BaseLayout>
      <Routes>
          <Route path = "/" element = {<App />} />
          <Route path = "/add-book" element = {<AddNewBook />} />
          <Route path = "/name" element = {<Name />} />
          <Route path = "/books/:id" element = {<BookDetail />} />
      </Routes>
      </BaseLayout>
```

The problem is when I go to BookDetail I cannot access the parameters using

```
this.props.history.match.params.id 


class BookDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props) // this.props is empty object 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>BookDetail</h1>
        )
    }
}


Even this.props is an empty object.
```

And NO for this project I cannot use hooks.

**UPDATE (SOLUTION):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

class BookDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.props is always empty object 
        console.log(this.props.params.id)
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <h1>BookDetail</h1>
        )
    }
}

const withRouter = (Component) => (props) => {
    const history = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const params = useParams(); 
    return <Component params = {params} history={history} location={location} {...props} />;
};

export default withRouter(BookDetail)
```

Comment: You are not passing props

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you will need to create a wrapper component to pass those properties:

```
const WithRouter = (Component) => (props) => {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  return <Component history={history} location={location} {...props} />;
};
```

then in your BookDetails file:

```
export default WithRouter(BookDetails);
```

Comment: Where exactly am I typing this code? ?

Comment: You can export BookDetails--> `export default WithRouter(BookDetails)`....or create a variable BookDetailRoute = WithRouter(BookDetails), then use this component on your routes

Comment: So I can access the this.props with your code but there is no way to get access to the params. this.props.location.????

Comment: I added useParams and now it is working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, also you can create this HOCs individually depend on what you need, `function withParams(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You're using react-router v6 which history is no longer working, History has been replaced with useNavigate.
In function component, this can be very easy because you've to replace useHistory() with useNavigate but if you prefer to use class component, check out this solution:
[How to use react-router-dom v6 navigate in class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143135/how-to-use-react-router-dom-v6-navigate-in-class-component)