# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.history is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

learning on Udemy part of the course work isnt working for me despite using the same codes as the video. The code should allow me to do a search based on username with option to go directly to the profile or a database of results. But I am getting Uncaught TypeError: this.props.history is undefined at main.js
Main.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route ,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

class Main extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        Data:'',
        checked:false
    };
  }

  handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState(()=>({
        checked:!this.state.checked
    }))
  }

  Search= (e)=> {
    console.log(this.state.Data)
    if(this.state.Data==='')return alert('Search field cannot be empty!')
    if(this.state.checked){
        this.props.history.push({
            Pathname:`/Specific/${this.state.Data}`,
        })
    }else{
        this.props.history.push({
            Pathname:`/Data/${this.state.Data}`,
        })
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
        <section className="mainPage">
        <center>
            <div className="main" id="main">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div className="main__text-container">
                                <h1 className="main__title">
                                    GitFetch - Profile Finder for GitHub
                                </h1>
                                <p className="main__subtitle">
                                    Check out the repos, followers and more, just by entering a username!
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="check">
                                    <input className="" type="checkbox" name="checked" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.checked}/>
                                     Go Direct to The user Profile
                                </div>
                                    <input type="text" id="search" name="Data" className="btn btn-outline-primary" 
                                    placeholder={this.state.checked?'Go to user profile':'Enter username'} 
                                    onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})}}
                                    value={this.state.Data} 
                                    
                                    />
                                    <span>
                                        <button onClick={this.Search} className="btn btn-outline-primary">Search</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </center>
      </section>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

App.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/nav/nav';
import Main from './components/github/main';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route ,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={};
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
          <Nav/>
          
            <Router>
            <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Main/>}/>
            </Routes>
            </Router>
          
          

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

changed code to

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import withRouter from '../withRouter';

class Main extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        Data:'',
        checked:false
    };
    this.Search=this.Search.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState(()=>({
        checked:!this.state.checked
    }))
  }

  Search= (e)=> {
    console.log(this.state.Data)
    if(this.state.Data==='')return alert('Search field cannot be empty!')
    if(this.state.checked){
        this.props.history.push({
            Pathname:`/Specific/${this.state.Data}`,
        })
    }else{
        this.props.navigate({
            Pathname:`/Data/${this.state.Data}`,
        })
    }
  }
```

but i am still unable to redirect users to the specified path with this.props.navigate({
Pathname:`/Data/${this.state.Data}`,
})

Comment: Props should be pass from the parent, so i guess in your App.tsx, the line of <Main/>  should be like `<Route exact path='/' element={<Main history={something}/>}/>`, could you check your video once more?

Comment: Hi thank you for the prompt reply. Video is only showing
<Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>

Comment: I see, the tutorial is still using react router dom v5, while you are probably using v6, which history is deprecated. 
You may have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143135/how-to-use-react-router-dom-v6-navigate-in-class-component

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys! 
How do I set a redirect ?
Using this.props.navigate({ Pathname:/Data/${this.state.Data}, }) does not redirect to the data specified

Comment: `this.props.router.push({ pathname: '/other-page'})`   try this

Comment: got it to work using this.props.navigate(`/Data/${this.state.Data}`) With V6 DOM and using Navigate instead of v5 dom as my tutorial >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `props` are empty and don't have `instance` of `history` , to provide `history` instance you need to wrap your component with `export default withRouter(Main)`

but `withRouter` has been deprecated in `react-router-dom v6` so if you are using this version or above then kindly write a `HOC` for `withRouter`

here is a reference to use `withRouter` for `v6` and above version of `react-router-dom`

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7256