# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.history.push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem that my `this.props` return `{}`, which is empty. But it suppose to be a room code.

`RoomJoinPage.js`

```
import React, { Component } from  'react';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import 
{ 
    Button, 
    Grid, 
    Typography, 
    TextField,
    FormHelperText,
    FormControl,
    Radio,
    RadioGroup,
    FormControlLabel
} from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            roomCode: "",
            error: "",
        };
        this._handleTextFieldChange = this._handleTextFieldChange.bind(this);
        this.roomButtonPress = this.roomButtonPress.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={ 1 }>
                
                <Grid item xs={12} align="center" >
                    <Typography variant='h4' component="h4">
                        Join a Room
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
                    <TextField 
                    error= {this.state.error}
                    label="Code"
                    placeholder="Enter a room code"
                    value= {this.state.roomCode}
                    helperText= {this.state.error}
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange}
                    />
                </Grid>

                <Grid
                container
                spacing={1}
                style={{width: "100", padding: 10}}
                direction="column"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignContent="center"
                >
                
                    <Grid item  xs={12}>
                        <Button variant='contained' color='secondary' onClick={this.roomButtonPress}>Enter room</Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Button variant='contained' color='primary' to='/' component={Link}>Back</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
    _handleTextFieldChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            roomCode: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    roomButtonPress(e) {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                code: this.state.roomCode
            })
        };
        console.log(this.props)
        fetch('/api/join-room', requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                this.props.history.push(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`)
            }
            else {
                this.setState({error: "Room not found."})
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error); 
        });
    }
}
```

The problem should be in the `roomButtonPress` function. I am new to react, how can I pass the `this.props` to that function?

The expected result is, when I click the `Enter Room` button with the correct room code (connected to Django backend), it should redirect to the room page, `/room/roomCode`

I used `RoomJoinPage` in `HomePage.js`

```
import React, { Component } from  'react';
import RoomJoinPage from './RoomJoinPage';
import CreateRoomPage from './CreateRoomPage';
import Room from './Room';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
         <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={<p> <h1>This is the home page</h1>
                    <a href='./join'> Link to room join page </a>
                    <br/><a href='./create'> Link to room create page </a>
                    <br/><a href='./api/home'> API? </a>
                    </p>}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/join' element={<RoomJoinPage></RoomJoinPage>}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/create' element={<CreateRoomPage></CreateRoomPage>}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/room/:roomCode' element={<Room></Room>}></Route>
            </Routes>
         </Router>   
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `RoomJoinPage`?

Comment: I used it as frontend, I am referencing the YouTube channel, maybe I post the link in the post. Thanks for your reply! @CertainPerformance

Comment: Please show the actual code where you use `RoomJoinPage` (not a link, people aren't going to go through a 35 minute video)

Comment: Apparently, `RoomJoinPage` is not being passed any props, hence `this.props` is `{}`. As @CertainPerformance said, we can't help you without seeing how the component is being used, and the info has to be **in** the question **as text**, not just as a link. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. More: [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Sorry about that, I will update it now

Comment: @eulerisgod Looks like you havent integrated React Router in page. Check your tutorial or this https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you havent integrated React Router in page.

Try these changes in `RoomJoinPage.js`

Include `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

Change

```
 export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
```

to

```
 class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
```

End of the page, export component with `withRouter`

```
 const NewRoomJoinPage = withRouter(RoomJoinPage);
 export default NewRoomJoinPage;
```

Comment: I got the other error, `Identifier 'HomePage' has already been declared. (18:6)`

Comment: It is `class HomePage extends Component {`

Comment: In `RoomJoinPage.js`, just have `import HomePage from './HomePage';` else

Comment: May bad, it should be `RoomJoinPage`, I will update answer

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: A new error then, `TypeError: (0,react_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.withRouter) is not a function. (In '(0,react_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.withRouter)(RoomJoinPage)', '(0,react_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.withRouter)' is undefined)`

Really thanks for your help, but I'm really confuse about it

Comment: This could be an issue with the react router you are using. Which version of the react router are you using

Comment: `npm list react-router` should show the version

Comment: I am using 6.3.0, is it different?

Comment: Yes, thats the issue, `withRouter` is removed in v6. v6 moved to functional components. So either downgrade to v5 or use `withRouter` as mentioned like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143135/how-to-use-react-router-dom-v6-navigate-in-class-component)