# Render toastify using a function dynamically

Tags: reactjs, toast, react-functional-component, chakra-ui

I am dealing with a form taking input  and am validating it. I want to show the validation error that a function returns using Toasts. Its quire redundant to go toast({}) and write down the status (success,error,etc) and the message for each type. Further on I will have to re write the same code in case I use another form in the website.

What i was thinking was to make a component that returns the toast and i just have to pass the status and message to it, but I cant figure out how to do so.

I am using chakra-ui but react solution of the same would also suffice for further projects.

I have tried this:

```
import { Button, useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Toast from "../Components/Toast"

export default function Abc() {
  const toast = useToast()

  const ToastDisplay = () =>{
    return (
      {Toast}
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Button onClick={()=>{ToastDisplay()}}>
      show toast
    </Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Toast.jsx file:

```
import { useColorMode } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react"

export default function Toast() {
    const toast = useToast();

    const optionsForToast = {
        position: "bottom-right",
        autoClose: 300,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "dark"
    }
    console.log(optionsForToast)

    return (
        toast({
            title:"hii"
        })
    )
}
```

I have tried directly using Toast function that is imported inside onClick in this way:

```
onClick={()=>{Toast()}}
```

It gives me an error in the console-

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have also tried replacing with <Toast /> both inside onClick and the ToastDisplay function (removes the error).

Further replacing `ToastDisplay()`  with `ToastDisplay` also removes the error from console but doesnt render the Toast.

Comment: Try using HOC to achieve this. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227055/3183454

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook that wraps the original toast hook and returns the function with a default config:

```
const useCustomToast = () => {
  const toast = useToast();
  
  return (params) => ({
    position: "bottom-right",
    autoClose: 300,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    closeOnClick: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    draggable: true,
    progress: undefined,
    theme: "dark",
    ...params
  });
}
```