# How to replace match.params with useParams() in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

In `react-router` v6 the `match.params` has been removed, with only the `useParams()` hook available. Now I can't figure out the tweak. The code below is made on Router v4. How can I make the indicated code work using `useParams()`. Can't figure it out:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Palette from "./Palette";
import Seeds from "./Seeds";
import { makePalette } from "./ColorHelpers.js";
import { Route, Routes, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  findPalette(id) {
    return Seeds.find(function (palette) {
      return palette.id === id;
    });
  }

  routeProps() {
    let id = useParams()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<h1>PALETTE LIST GOES HERE</h1>} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/palette/:id"
          render={routeProps => ( // <-- this code
            <Palette
              palette={makePalette(
                this.findPalette(routeProps.match.params.id)
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the `render` to `element` and removing the arrow function `routeProps => ()` into a separate function with `useParams()`.

Comment: I think refactoring to functional component can help here!

Comment: Just FYI, the `props.match` wasn't replaced by the `useParams` hook, `react-router@5` has the `useParams` hook too. What changed is the `Route` component API; route props were removed in `react-rotuer@6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to use the `useParams` hook inside a class component, which won’t work since hooks can’t be used directly in class components. Either refactor your component as a functional component or wrap it in a higher order component as described here:

[How can I use React hooks in React classic `class` component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371356/how-can-i-use-react-hooks-in-react-classic-class-component)

Once you do so, you can destructure the id parameter returned from the `useParams` hook:

```
const {id} = useParams();
```

Move this destructured assignment out of the `routeProps` function into the body of the functional component. Then you can access id in your bolded lines with `findPalette(id)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Don't know how I missed the fact that useParams doesn't work inside a class component. this was  big help